# Python optional, positional and keyword arguments

Tags: python, optional-arguments, keyword-argument

This is a class I have:

```
class metadict(dict):
    def __init__(self, do_something=False, *args, **kwargs)
        if do_something:
            pass
        super(metadict,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
```

The idea is to encapsulate a dictionary and add some functionality with a special keyword. The dictionary can still hold `do_something` though you can't add it at creation time. For all other aspects it behaves just like a normal dictionary.

Anyway, the problem is that whatever I give to `args` it starts by assigning the first value to `do_something` which is not what I want.

What I do now is this:

```
class metadict(dict):
    def __init__(self, do_something=False, *args, **kwargs)
        if not isinstance(do_something, bool):
            args = list(args)
            args.append(do_something)
        elif do_something:
            pass
        super(metadict,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
```

But it doesn't look right to me. I could also check for the `do_something` value in kwargs, but it will be worse, since I mess with the signature removing useful information...

Is there any way in python to use optional, positional and keyword arguments safely?
If not  are there other simpler workarounds?

I'm on python 2.6

Comment: I believe the issue is that you're defining a keyword argument before a positional argument (`do_something` being a keyword, `*args` being the positionals). Then when you pass a value as the first element in the constructor, it is getting passed to `do_something`. Try putting `do_something` after `*args`.

Comment: @RocketDonkey I did try it but apparently is not supported in python 2.6

Comment: Ah, interesting. Well in any case, looks like you got it sorted out, so good luck with everything!

Comment: @RocketDonkey well I haven't, but if this is there in version 3.0 it means there's no simple workaround. So I'm just out of luck.

Comment: So this is messy, may cause additional issues and definitely not answer-worthy (enough disclaimers? :) ), but one thing that works* for me is not unpacking `*args` (so using `args` instead). You can then put your `do_something=False` after `args`, making your signature `self, args, do_something=False, **kwargs`. Then when you call `super`, use  `.__init__(args, **kwargs)`. *This doesn't work if you use the `dict(one=1, two=2)` syntax, since it relies on being passed an iterable that is then unpacked by the `dict` class itself. Again, horrible solution, but if you're desperate... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's [new in Python 3](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/). The best workaround in Python 2 is

```
def foo(*args, **kwargs):
    do_something = kwargs.pop("do_something", False)
```

The behaviour you see happens because Python tries to be clever in matching up arguments, so for instance it will make a keyword argument positional if you pass too many positional arguments.

PS why not store it as an attribute of `metadict` instead of as an entry in the dict?

Comment: If the OP worries about the signature, the solution is simple...document the function. A good documentation, with allowed parameters, default values and so-on if often better than a long signature.

Comment: The attribute affects creation and is not stored at all. Basically it tells if present, the dictionary will be created using a special construct for providing metadata information to the dictionary, if not is (almost) completely transparent. @EnricoGiampieri Documentation is great and I'll do that, but you miss semantics. So `inspect` won't work properly and neither will documentation tools like `sphinx`. Bottom line it's just a design decision.